# How do you display content of a .JSON file using Discord.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, discord.js

Currently my code reads out as

```js
if(message.content.startsWith(prefix + 'readback')) {

  fs.readFile('msgs.json', (err, data) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    let _msgs = JSON.parse(data);
    message.channel.send(_msgs);
    console.log(_msgs)
  });
}
```

with all appropriate constants and variables

While using `prefix + 'readback`, the Discord Bot displays `_msgs` as `[object Object]` - to make sure it wasn't an issue with the code, I added `console.log(_msgs)`, and the correct JSON file content displays in the console. Is there a way to get the Bot to display the contents of the JSON file in a channel?

Comment: message.channel.send() converts _msgs to a string using the toString() method, which would return something like [object Object] for a json object; you might want to try using JSON.stringify()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can take advantage of [discord markdown](https://support.discordapp.com/hc/en-us/articles/210298617-Markdown-Text-101-Chat-Formatting-Bold-Italic-Underline-).

Code block, as on Stack Overflow, can be used to format code and even add color:

````
```json  
{
    "some": "json"
}
```
````

will render like this:
[image]

Now, as stated by Xander Kyle in comment, you want to use `JSON.stringify` as `message.channel.send` use `toString` to convert variable to string and it doesn't work "as you want" for objects.

````js
fs.readFile('msgs.json', (err, data) => {
  if (err) { throw err; }
  const _msgs = JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(data), null, 2);
  message.channel.send('```json\n' + _msgs + '\n```');
  console.log(_msgs)
});
````

The `2` in stringify make the json indented ([documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify))

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I used, it sends an object formatted as JSON to the channel.

````js
var msg = '\```json\n{'
for (var key in jsobj) {
    if (jsobj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        msg = msg + "\n \"" + key + "\": \"" + jsobj[key] + "\","
    }                        
}
msg = msg.substring(0, msg.length - 1)
msg = msg + "\n}\`\`\`"
message.channel.send(msg);
````

The `jsobj` variable will be your JSON object.

Answer (score -1):

```
fs.readFile('msgs.json', (err, data) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  let _msgs = JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(data), null, 2);
   message.channel.send(_msgs);
   console.log(_msgs)
});
```

This will format the JSON as multi-line with 2-space indentation.

If you do:

```
message.channel.send(data);
```

Then you'll get JSON but with no formatting.